# Typo3 Direct Mail - wrong file/folder permissions

Tags: permissions, typo3

I have installed these extensions in exact the listed order:

1. tt_address
2. direct_mail
3. direct_mail_subscription

Now I cant access the Direct Mail modules in the BE.
I get this error:

[image]

Sorry for the stupid question, but I didn't found nothing via google.
How can I find out which folder/files have the wrong permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is struggling with the same issue, I found the files.

Within the folder `typo3conf/ext/direct_mail` are several `mod*` folder. Change the file permissions to 644 solved the issue.